# Asserting with extension methods

Tags: c#, unit-testing, testing

I'm currently using a library called Visual Studio Testing Extensions (http://vstestingextensions.codeplex.com/), which lets me write assertions in the following way:

```
var result = unitUnderTest.MyImportantMethod();

result.ShouldBePositive();
      .ShouldBeGreaterThan(4)
      .ShouldBeLessThan(5.55);
```

Unfortunately, the library wasn't updated for more than 2 years now and is barely used (120 downloads). Is there maybe a library that is more commonly used and is still being developed?

To be clear, I would like the following features:

- Asserting with extension methods instead of Assert.xxx methods.
- Chaining assertions in a fluent syntax

Also, NUnit support is necessary.

Comment: I am not aware of one but I've been looking for a project to take on, thanks for the idea!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

doesn't [fluent assertions](https://github.com/dennisdoomen/FluentAssertions) do what you want?

I'm not sure about the 'NUnit support is neccessary' statement as isn't the libarry you want going to replace the NUnit assertions anyway?

Comment: I'm replacing the NUnit assertions, but I'm keeping the testing framework.